# Many assignments from incompatible pointer type C

Tags: c, pointers

I'm pretty new to C, and I don't have a very good grasp of pointers. I'm trying to build a hash table. Here's what I have so far.

I've been cobbling this together from several sources, and I've lost any idea I have of what the pointers are doing. If anyone could even give me a hint as to where my problem is I'd be very grateful.

Header File

```
 typedef struct {
   char * word;
   char * defn;
   struct entry *next;
 } entry;


 typedef struct {
   int size;
   struct entry **table;
 } hashTable;

 typedef hashTable * Dictionary;
```

Code

```
 #include "hashP.h"
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <limits.h>


 Dictionary create(int initial_capacity, int delta_capacity){
     Dictionary new_table;
     int i;

     if ((new_table = malloc(sizeof(Dictionary))) == NULL){
         return NULL;
     }

     if ((new_table->table = malloc(sizeof(entry *) * initial_capacity)) == NULL){
         return NULL;
     }

     for(i=0; i < initial_capacity; i++){
         new_table->table[i] = NULL;
     }
     return new_table;
 }


 /* Insert a key-value pair into a hash table. */
 void insertEntry(Dictionary table, char *index, char *value) {
     int bin = 0;
     entry *newpair = NULL;
     entry *next = NULL;
     entry *last = NULL;
     unsigned long int hashval;
     int i = 0;
     char *word = index;
     char *defn = value;

     /* Convert our string to an integer */
     while( hashval < ULONG_MAX && i < strlen(word) ) {
         hashval = hashval << 8;
         hashval += word[i];
         i++;
     }

     bin = hashval % table->size;

     next = table->table[bin];


     while( next != NULL && next->word != NULL && strcmp(word, next->word ) > 0 ) {
         last = next;
         next = next->next;
     }

     /* There's already a pair.  Let's replace that string. */
     if( next != NULL && next->word != NULL && strcmp( word, next->word ) == 0 ) {

         free( next->defn );
         next->defn = strdup(defn);

     /* Nope, could't find it.  Time to grow a pair. */
     } else {

         if( ( newpair = malloc( sizeof(entry) ) ) == NULL ) {
             return NULL;
         }

         if( ( newpair->word = strdup(word) ) == NULL ) {
             return NULL;
         }

         if( ( newpair->defn = strdup(defn) ) == NULL ) {
             return NULL;
         }

         newpair->next = NULL;

         /* We're at the start of the linked list in this bin. */
         if( next == table->table[ bin ] ) {
             newpair->next = next;
             table->table[bin] = newpair;

         /* We're at the end of the linked list in this bin. */
         } else if ( next == NULL ) {
             last->next = newpair;

         /* We're in the middle of the list. */
         } else  {
             newpair->next = next;
             last->next = newpair;
         }
     }
 }
```

Sorry for the huge wall of text. It gives me an "Assignment from incompatible pointer type" every time I use "next".

Comment: what is `Dictionary` ?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it to add the definition.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(Dictionary)` allocates the wrong amount of space. You can avoid this sort of error by using the pattern `new_table = malloc( sizeof *new_table );`

Comment: Pointer typedefs make the code harder to read; normally if someone sees a function taking `Foo` as parameter, they assume it's passing by value .

Comment: You have a potential memory leak if the first malloc succeeds but the second one fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you declare your struct as:

```c
struct entry { ... };
```

Then you should use it as

```
struct entry* next;
```

If you declare it as:

```c
typedef struct { ... } entry;
```

Then you should use it as

```
entry* next;
```

In this case `struct entry* next` will still compile (as in your case), but will refer to an incomplete type, which is **not** the `entry` that you defined. Assigning from something that is `entry*` to something that is `struct entry*` will, therefore, give you an error.

To fix your problem just replace all occurrences of `struct entry` with `entry`.

UPDATE: it will not work, because by the time you define `entry* next` `entry` itself is not defined yet. You can fix it like this, for example:

```
 typedef struct entry_t {
   char * word;
   char * defn;
   struct entry_t *next;
 } entry;
```

Comment: I got rid of the struct, but now I get this error in the header file "error: unknown type name "entry""

Comment: No, I only got rid of the specific one you mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, this in fact makes sense, because by the time you declare `next` `entry` is not defined yet. I will update my answer in a second.

Comment: Also fix the bug on the `Dictionary` allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Beside other problems, `Dictionary` is not defined.  From how you use it, I am guessing it is a `typedef` for a pointer to a `hashTable`.  The allocation is wrong, you allocate the size for a pointer, not for the `hashTable` structure. You should write:

```
Dictionary new_table = malloc(sizeof(*new_table));
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the line where I define Dictionary in the header file. I just added it.